# addRow styling in Label

Tags: lightningchart

I am adding custom formtable like below

```
return builder
        .addRow(name)
        .addRow(price)
```

Is there anyway to style the row ? I want to display the price with big font and different color.

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing built-in method for customizing each row/column of result table apart from the text content.

This is definitely a feature that we are eventually including in the library, as soon as it becomes a priority or a customer requests it.

Right now, as a community user, it can be done by creating a custom cursor. Unfortunately there aren't many examples on this subject.
The general idea is solving the nearest data point from mouse location with [`ChartXY.solveNearest`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/chartxy.html#solvenearest) (or calculating by some custom method), and showing the custom cursor using UI elements and custom ticks if desired.

The `ResultTable` can be created by combining `Column` and `Row` layouts to get a grid, and then adding `TextBox` elements, whose font/color you can style individually.

EDIT: The official examples for custom cursors have been released.
You can find them there https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/search.html?t=cursor

There is one example with LCJS UI elements and another with dynamic HTML & CSS (same approach could be used with some external UI framework).

Comment: Hi , can u give me some example ?

Comment: It's a bit too much work to reply here.
I will note this thread down, and probably in near future we will add an official example for creating custom cursors, which you can then refer to. We'll ping you here at that time.

Comment: Hi, development of the custom cursor example is on-going. Release is likely to be in 1-4 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of simple custom autoCursor

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
  lightningChart,
  AutoCursorModes,
  UIElementBuilders,
  UILayoutBuilders,
  UIBackgrounds,
  ColorHEX,
  SolidFill,
  SolidLine,
  UIOrigins,
  translatePoint,
} = lcjs;

// Import data-generator from 'xydata'-library.
const {
  createProgressiveTraceGenerator
} = xydata

// colors of the series
const colors = ["#fc03f0", "#1cb843", "#eeff00", "#0955ff", "#500c3f"];

// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart()
  .ChartXY({
    // theme: Themes.dark
  })
  // Disable native AutoCursor to create custom
  .setAutoCursorMode(AutoCursorModes.disabled)
  .setTitle("Custom Cursor using LCJS UI");

// set title for Y axis
chart.getDefaultAxisY().setTitle("Y-axis");

// generate data and creating the series
  const series = chart.addLineSeries().setStrokeStyle(
    new SolidLine({
      fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(colors[0]) }),
      thickness: 2,
    })
  );

  createProgressiveTraceGenerator()
    .setNumberOfPoints(200)
    .generate()
    .toPromise()
    .then((data) => {
      return series.add(data);
    });

// Create UI elements for custom cursor.
const resultTable = chart
  .addUIElement(
    UILayoutBuilders.Column.setBackground(UIBackgrounds.Rectangle),
    {
      x: chart.getDefaultAxisX(),
      y: chart.getDefaultAxisY(),
    }
  )
  .setMouseInteractions(false)
  .setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftBottom)
  .setMargin(2)
  .setBackground((background) =>
    background.setStrokeStyle(
      new SolidLine({
        thickness: 1,
        fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX("#c9bab9") }),
      })
    )
  );

const rowX = resultTable
  .addElement(UILayoutBuilders.Row)
  .addElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox)
  .setTextFont((font) => font.setSize(15))
  .setTextFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(colors[1]) }));

const rowY = resultTable
    .addElement(UILayoutBuilders.Row)
    .addElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox)
    .setTextFont((font) => font.setSize(15))
    .setTextFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(colors[2]) }));


// Hide custom cursor components initially.
resultTable.dispose();

// Implement custom cursor logic with events.
chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseMove((_, event) => {
  const mouseLocationClient = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
  // Translate mouse location to LCJS coordinate system for solving data points from series, and translating to Axes.
  const mouseLocationEngine = chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine(
    mouseLocationClient.x,
    mouseLocationClient.y
  );

  // Translate mouse location to Axis.
  const mouseLocationAxis = translatePoint(
    mouseLocationEngine,
    chart.engine.scale,
    series.scale
  );

  // Solve nearest data point to the mouse on each series.
  const nearestDataPoints = series.solveNearestFromScreen(mouseLocationEngine)

  if (nearestDataPoints) {
    // Set custom cursor location.
    resultTable.setPosition({
      x: nearestDataPoints.location.x,
      y: nearestDataPoints.location.y,
    });

  // set Origin of resultTable
  if ( nearestDataPoints.location.x > chart.getDefaultAxisX().getInterval().end / 1.5 ) {
    if (nearestDataPoints.location.y >chart.getDefaultAxisY().getInterval().end / 1.5) {
      resultTable.setOrigin(UIOrigins.RightTop);
    } else {
      resultTable.setOrigin(UIOrigins.RightBottom);
    }
  } else if ( nearestDataPoints.location.y > chart.getDefaultAxisY().getInterval().end / 1.5) {
    resultTable.setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftTop);
  } else {
    resultTable.setOrigin(UIOrigins.LeftBottom);
  }

    // Format result table text.
    rowX.setText(`X: ${nearestDataPoints.location.x.toFixed(1)}`);
    rowY.setText(`Y: ${nearestDataPoints.location.y.toFixed(1)}`)
    // Display cursor.
    resultTable.restore();
  } else {
    // Hide cursor.
    resultTable.dispose();
  }
});

chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseLeave((_, e) => {
  resultTable.dispose();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/xydata@1.4.0/dist/xydata.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.0.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: if the mouse is hovered on extreme right label is hiding on rightside... when will official API to style the labels will be released.

Comment: Hi! you can use 'setOrigin' method to change position of resutlTable relative to cursor. You'll find the code in my code snippet after comment "// set Origin of resultTable". 
Here you can have a look at Custom cursor examples

https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/search.html?t=cursor